# modification of lists with respect to dates

Tags: r, list

I have a list data

```
list <- list()
list$date <- structure(19297:19310, class = "Date")
list$value <- c(100,200,300,100,200,300,100,200,300,100,200,500,800)
list$temp2 <- c(1000,2000,3000,1000,2000,3000,1000,2000,3000,1000,2000,5888,9887)
```

I want to modify the list in such a way that:

- every element of the list$value is multiplied with 0.5 * list$temp2 (which can be done by a multiply operation)
- Except the maximum of the value that is in between days 1 to 7 of the date (maximum of first week) - this maximum value needs to be doubled. (i.e., only one list$value doesn't get replaced with the step 1 rather is doubled by its own value)

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting the list into a data.frame (or better yet a data.table) will enable column-wise operations on the data.

```
dl <- list()
dl$date <- structure(19297:19310, class = "Date")
dl$value <- c(100,200,300,100,200,300,100,200,300,100,200,500,800)
dl$temp2 <- c(1000,2000,3000,1000,2000,3000,1000,2000,3000,1000,2000,5888,9887)
```

Since the list elements are unequal length, adding NAs to the end, so there are 14 elements in each value

```
dl$value[[length(dl$value)+1]] <- NA
dl$temp2[[length(dl$temp2)+1]] <- NA
```

Convert to a data.frame

```
df <- as.data.frame(dl)
```

Create the exception criteria (max value of the first 7 days)

```
df$exception <- df$value == max(df[1:7,"value"])
df$exception[is.na(df$exception)] <- FALSE
```

Create a new variable "value2" and perform the multiplications .5 where the exception doesn't occur, and x2 where it does occur.

```
df$value2 <- as.numeric(NA)
df$value2[df$exception == FALSE] <- df$value[df$exception == FALSE] * 0.5
df$value2[df$exception == TRUE] <- df$value[df$exception == TRUE] * 2
```

The output, which can be passed back into a list object, if required

```
df$date
df$value2
df$temp2
```

Comment: while writing an exception - is there any other way where I can check the 1:7 ? because I do not always have the dates starting from 01

Comment: Yes, but it's hard to suggest other approaches without knowing other ways the dates might be sorted?  I suppose you could max(sort(df$value)[1:7]) to guarantee the first 7 elements are sorted?

Comment: The dates are already sorted. But I do not know from where the dates start - it might start from 11th of a month or 15th of a month and so on

Comment: It's not really clear what the criteria is for the exception rule you want to create.  The original question asks in terms of the max value of the first 7 elements; but it seems this isn't actually the criteria you want.  I'm happy to suggest, but more details are needed.  You could modify the question to give additional requirements?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74606873/date-specific-manipulation-in-a-list-in-r.

Comment: please refer this question

Comment: Sure, I'll take a look.  I think the suggested answer does address the posted question -- if you agree, I'd appreciate if you can accept the answer.